# Dynamic PHP Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a function that takes in a string (`$skill`), and a list of allowed characters in a regex.

Here is the requirements on the homework

> 1. Skill-name: required; can't be too long; can contain spaces, hyphens, apostrophes (and of course alphanumeric characters), but no other characters
> 2. As part of this step, you must have a php function that takes in a string and a list of allowed characters (or, dis-allowed characters, or perhaps even a regular expression), and returns a an error message (if the string doesn't match the requirement), or the empty string (if the string does match the requirement). Be sure to give a descriptive name to this function.

This is the code I have

```
function validate_skill($skill, $list) { 
if (preg_match('/['.$list.']/',$skill)) {
        echo "The skill contains a match.<br />";
    }else{
    echo "The skill does not contain a match.";
    }
}
```

I'm only receiving a blank page, and through commenting out the function, the page then works. Is this the proper way to have a variable be inside an expression?

Comment: Blank page means you didn't enable error_reporting. Don't come back until you do. And the character list placed there might need to be escaped, see preg_quote.

Comment: did you mean else? you typed echo twice

Comment: ini_set('display_errors','stderr');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','stderr');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); I do have error reporting on

Comment: @PeeHaa Might be the syntax error just as likely; and if, it's too localized.

Comment: @PRPGFerret It needs to be enabled *before* you include or invoke a page containing fatal/syntax errors.

Comment: In order to display syntax errors, error reporting needs to be enabled from `php.ini`, make sure you do so.

Comment: It was a syntax error.. the way my school sets up page space it doesn't tell me syntax errors =/ And I can't alter my schools php.ini, I'm not allowed

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've either misunderstood your requirements, or you're approaching this wrong. Here's the simplified version of the requirements:

1. The function should have 2 arguments, the skill name, and some sort of validation string (in your case, list of allowed characters, a.k.a a *whitelist*). Got that ✔
2. The skill name shouldn't be very long. This means you need to limit the length. ✘
3. By **validating** that the string matched the allowed character list, you need to make sure that it matched **only** those, and ***nothing else***. Right now, you're checking if **any of the characters in the list is found**. ✘
4. The function should **return** the error (or nothing), therefore, it should not **echo** anything by itself. ✘

You should be working on those points.

Also, on a different note, you have a syntax error. `echo echo`, should probably be `else echo`.